# Neo4j distance vs PostGIS distance with spatial data

Tags: postgis, st-distance, neo4j

Does anyone know how the distance function of neo4j/cypher works exactly?

When i compare the evaluated distances between neo4j and postgis, i always get a difference of about 0.1-0.5%.

As postgis `st_distance` uses an srid i assume that the problem is the distance function from neo4j.

Answer (score 3):

The Neo4j implementation is considering great circle distances (see [distance calculation documentation](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/a360534d-a7dd-41a8-9d2a-8bdbc6dbc181)). The earth radius is set to 6,371,000 meters (see [implementation](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.1/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/util/GeoEstimateEvaluator.java) on GitHub).

The [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) states that the `ST_Distance` function

> returns the 2D Cartesian distance between two geometries in projected
>   units (based on spatial ref). For geography type defaults to return minimum geodesic distance between two geographies in meters.

I am assuming you are using WGS84 coordinates and geography types in PostGIS. WGS84 (EPSG 4326) is defined with a radius of 6,378,137 meters ([spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/html/)) which explains the deviations. Deviations will grow with the actual distance of points.

Comment: The question needs to be clarified, but I would assume PostGIS data are *not* in EPSG:4326 because `ST_Distance`, as you describe, calculates a Cartesian distance in the SRID's coordinate units. So the distance from New York to Sao Paulo is 69.88 because the unit is decimal degrees. OTH, maybe OP is using the `geography` data type?

Comment: You are right. I assume he is using the geography type and EPSG:4326 coordinates which provides results in meters (using the `ST_Distance` function). Otherwise  `ST_Distance_Sphere` could be used for the geometry type and EPSG:4326 coordinates to get the distance in meters too.